# Socket getaddrinfo()-equivalent function for VxWorks?

Tags: c++, sockets, vxworks, cross-compiling

As far as I can tell, there is no getaddrinfo() function for VxWorks. Is there any equivalent, or are there any examples of how to roll your own?

Alternatively, what would be another method to populate an addrinfo structure for use with sockets?

**EDIT:**
For anyone who stumbles upon this question, I must say that there *are* getaddrinfo() and freeaddrinfo() functions located in "netdb.h".

Comment: Are you trying to look up an IP address by name?

Comment: I am basically trying to do the exact same thing as getaddrinfo. I'm writing a cross-platform library for Windows, VxWorks, GNU/Linux, and many other POSIX standard operating systems. I would like to be able to populate an addrinfo structure given the parameters of the POSIX getaddrinfo (i.e. an IPv4 IPv6 OR address name, a port number or service name, and the appropriate addrinfo structures).

Comment: I think you'd be best served by making each of those lookups a separate function in your library.  If several of them wind up calling the same `getaddrinfo` function (with different options) on some operating systems, that's an implementation detail.  But `getaddrinfo` is an ugly API, that tries to do too many different things -- I wouldn't try to copy those flaws in my own design.

Comment: My next library is actually going to be a network utility library that does exactly what you're describing. I'm basically just using getaddrinfo for some minor, optional automation functions for the socket library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no access to a VxWorks system, my crystal ball tells me `salSocketFind`.

Comment: Doesn't look exactly analogous, but definitely workable. You also opened my eyes to the whole SAL client and server libraries in VxWorks. Thanks!